# SELECT database.table.column in Hive

Tags: hive

Is it possible to use

```
SELECT DB.TABLE.COLUMN from DB.TABLE
```

in Hive?

I know it's possible to alias `DB.TABLE` as follows

```
SELECT T1.COLUMN FROM DB.TABLE AS T1
```

But, is there any way in Hive to select a column fully qualified by its database and table name, as shown in the first query above? I've done this before in MySQL but I don't know if there's a way to make Hive work this way.

Answer (score 0):

No, that is not possible in Hive, you will get an exception:

```
SemanticException [Error 10004]: Line 1:7 Invalid table alias or column reference 'DB': (possible column names are: col)
```

And your second select sentence is valid.
To specify a database, either qualify the table names with database names ("db_name.table_name" starting in Hive 0.7) or issue the USE statement before the query statement (starting in Hive 0.6).

See language manual here: [LanguageManual+Select](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Select)